# dynamically adding views in a particular position

Tags: java, android

I am adding dynamically views on button click.In that views there is a imageview.After clicking on the imageview i am adding a photos from gallery.It's working till now.Now the problem is the photo is set in the wrong position.It means it is adding only at the last view .How it can be solved.Thanks in advance.

```
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                    (LayoutInflater)  getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add, null);
            EditText textOut = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            //   textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString());

            img = (ImageView) addView.findViewById(R.id.takephoto);
            img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    img.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Here is my add.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/takephoto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:src="@drawable/ic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:hint="Enter Option"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLength="40" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's your main layout? I guess it's `LinearLayout`. `addView` is linear or relative layout?

Comment: the main layout is scrolllayout and addview is in linear layout

Comment: Change it in to RelativeLayout and try

Comment: nope,it doesn't work.

Comment: Share a screenshot. It will be clear

Comment: I can't cause it's a client app.

Comment: can you make a sample or share a sketch so that we can understand? http://sketchtoy.com/

Comment: http://sketchtoy.com/63455174 .Here you can see I have created two imageview.when i click on the first imageview it's always adding image to the last imageview that has been created.